# C++ Add New Line at End of File If On Is Not Present?

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io, formatting, newline

I am writing a program in C++ which opens, parses, and formats a text file. I would like to know if there is a way that I could open the text file, check and see if there a new line at the end of the file, and add one if it is not present.

I am very new to C++, and I am not sure how to tackle this. Could someone please provide a demo?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on paulsm4's answer:

```
//Open file in append-binary mode.
FILE *hFile = fopen("C:\\Test.txt", "ab");
if(hFile == NULL)
{
    printf("File not found.\n");
    return 0;
}

//Seek one character from the end of the file.
fseek(hFile, -1, SEEK_END);

//Read in a single character;
char cLastChar = fgetc(hFile);

if(cLastChar != '\n')
{
    //Write the line-feed.
    fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, hFile);
}

//Close the file handle.
fclose(hFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. fopen () file
2. fseek() to filesize - 1
3. If the character isn't "\n", then append one

Comment: Excellent! Just for clarity, could you format that in an example that I could follow?

Comment: Ah, I suggest looking up the functions and trying to get them working on the smallest scale you can. Once you do that, work them into what you need.